# Python docx - Add Page breaks inside a table row

Tags: python, python-docx

I have seen the code to create Page breaks using `document.create_page_break()` and `run.add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)`. But I am trying to add page breaks within a table row and unfortunately cant get it working.
The below code will explain what I am trying to do.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

document = Document('sampledoc.docx')
tables = document.tables

for str1 in ["test string 1", "test string 2", "test string 3", "test string 4"]:
    para = tables[1].rows[0].cells[0].add_paragraph()
    run = para.add_run()
    run.add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
    run = para.add_run('\n' + str1 + '\n')

document.save("sampledoc2.docx")
```

The strings in the list are getting added, but I see no breaks in between them. Can any one help?